# Using stringstream as a stack of strings

Tags: c++, stack, std, stringstream

I am trying to do something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> firstLevel = {...}; //some strings
std::vector<std::string> secondLevel = {...}; //some strings
std::stringstream strm;
std::string garbage;
for (std::string i : firstLevel){
        strm << i << "/";
        for (std::string j : secondLevel){
            strm << j;
            std::cout << strm.str() << std::endl; // print the whole string
            strm >>garbage; //somthing similar to "pop" is required here
        }
        strm >>garbage; //somthing similar to "pop" is required here
}
```

but it takes the whole string out of "strm", and I want it to simply take out the last inserted one.
Is there a way to take out the last string that was inserted (using the "<<" operator) into a stringstream variable? I am looking for something like the "push" and "pop" ability of a stack, but I want my variable to remain of type "stringstream".

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a stream of characters, not of strings, and has no "memory". This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is your ultiate goal?

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: You can separate your strings by inserting one or more spaces between them. However, your stringstream object will *not* be a stack (LIFO); it will be first-in, first-out (FIFO). If you want a stack, then maybe use `std::stack`?

Comment: In the inner loop, why are you even writing `j` to the stream if you want it to be extracted the very next instant? Would it be possible to just write `std::cout<<stream.str()<<j<<std::endl`?  IMHO `stringstream` appears ill-suited here.

Comment: It is close to wanting to use a vector of int to handle a mapping string -> float. It might be possible with a lot of work, but it is not an appropriate tools. If you really want to go that way, you could use a vector of integers to store the positions of the strings in the stringstream and seek over the stringstream. But **really** what is the rationale for not directly using a stack of strings???

Comment: I think I'll simply use a stack, as suggested. It'll make it a bit more ugly then I wanted it to be, but I guess it is the correct approach, rather then manipulating stringstream.

Comment: This is still clasic example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are using `stringstream` in some strange context, but you didn't explained what this code suppose to do. Most probably if we could knew what are you doing, nobody would be propose use of `std::stingstream`.

Comment: This example is trivially solved without any "external" structure; `for (auto i : firstLevel) for (auto j: secondLevel) cout << i << '/' << j << endl;`. Do you have an example where the stack behaviour is meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to reset the `std::stringstream`. For that, you can use the str() method. As you are using it (no parameter) it just returns the content, but if you pass a string to it, its content gets reset to the string. So if you want to clear the stringstream, you would just do:

```
strm.str("");
```